# Parsing function for a server, using the Jansson library

Tags: c, json

I'm making a server in C that needs to parse JSON that follows oBIX protocol and I'm using the [Jansson library](https://jansson.readthedocs.org/en/2.5/) for this. I've been programming in high level languages such as Java and C# for my entire career and the last time I touched C was way back in 7-8 years ago, so I'm mostly looking for guidance on writing C-style code.

Here's a sample JSON input from client to server:

```
{"obix":"obj","is":"obix:Request","rid":"1","children":[{"obix":"op","name":"add","is":"obix:Watch","children":[{"obix":"obj","is":"obix:WatchIn","children":[{"obix":"list","names":"hrefs","children":[{"obix":"uri","val":"/device/"}]}]}]}]}
```

So a function I have just needs to validate what kind of request the client is making. First, I write the following defines:

```
#define OBIX_REQUEST_INVALID -1
#define OBIX_REQUEST_WATCH 0
#define OBIX_REQUEST_UPDATE 1 
....
```

Then in my callback function. I first validate whether it's a valid JSON input.

```
int callback_web_socket(struct libwebsocket_context * this,
                                   struct libwebsocket *wsi,
                                   enum libwebsocket_callback_reasons reason,
                                   void *user, void *in, size_t len)
{
    ....

    json_t *root;
    json_error_t error;

    root = json_loads(buf,0,&error);
    if (!root)
    {
         printf("\nInvalid JSON data.\n");
         break;
    }
    ....
```

If it's valid JSON, I call my parse function to determine request type

```
int request_type = obix_parse_request(root);
printf("\nRequest Type: %d\n", request_type);
```

And here's how my parse function looks like:

```
int obix_parse_request(const json_t *obix_root_obj) {
    json_t *obix_obj = json_object_get(obix_root_obj,"obix");

    if (!json_is_string(obix_obj) || strcmp(json_string_value(obix_obj),"obj") != 0) {
        return OBIX_REQUEST_INVALID;
    }

    json_t *first_child = json_object_get(obix_root_obj, "children");
    if (!first_child || !json_is_array(first_child)) {
        return OBIX_REQUEST_INVALID;
    }

    json_t *first_child_obj = json_array_get(first_child, 0);
    if (!first_child_obj || !json_is_object(first_child_obj)) {
        return OBIX_REQUEST_INVALID;
    }

    json_t *first_child_is_str = json_object_get(first_child_obj, "is");
    if (!first_child_is_str || !json_is_string(first_child_is_str)) {
        return OBIX_REQUEST_INVALID;
    }

    const unsigned char *request_type = json_string_value(first_child_is_str);
    if (strcmp(request_type, "obix:Watch") == 0) {
        return OBIX_REQUEST_WATCH;
    }

    ...
}
```

If I were coding in C#, this function would raise a huge red flag for lots of code duplication. But this is C, and I'm readily assuming the code duplication is part of my incompetency in C language.

How would you elegantly write this function? Aside from cleaning up the function, I'd like to hear some comments on my coding style.

Comment: It is better to use const and enums than #define, because #define's are I scoped and unchecked.

Comment: Also, at compile time the preprocessor macros get replaced by their numerical value in the code, so it will be difficult to determine what a number is all about when debugging.

Comment: I would Lex and yacc it makes it very simple.

Answer (score 10):

A few notes:

- My first concern with your program is the use of the Jansson library.  [Looking at some benchmarks](http://chadaustin.me/2013/01/json-parser-benchmarking/) shows me that it is less than stellar. (The Y-axis is parses-per-second. Thus, higher is faster.)

  [image]

  So a new library choice may be in order.  I would highly recommend looking a [jsmn](http://zserge.com/jsmn.html). I have yet to find a faster (and more portable!) option out there.  Here is a benchmark for jsmn compared to Jansson (jsmn is 19.28 times faster).

  \$ 
  \newcommand\T{\Rule{0pt}{1em}{.5em}}
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline \textbf{Project} & \textbf{License} & \textbf{API} & \textbf{Neg. tests} & \textbf{Followers} & \textbf{Benchmark} \T \\\hline
    \text{Jansson} \T & \text{MIT} & \text{DOM} & \text{yes} & \dfrac{234}{59} & 25 \text{MB/s}, 52 \text{s} \\\hline
    \text{jsmn} \T & \text{MIT} & \text{custom} & \text{yes} & \dfrac{65}{4} & 482 \text{MB/s}, 2.3 \text{s} \\\hline
  \end{array}
  \$
- You have used the preprocessor to define some oBIX request values.

  > ```
  > #define OBIX_REQUEST_INVALID -1
  > #define OBIX_REQUEST_WATCH 0
  > #define OBIX_REQUEST_UPDATE 1
  > ```

  You could use an `enum` here instead.

  ```
  typedef enum 
  {
      INVALID = -1,
      WATCH = 0,
      UPDATE = 1
  } ObixRequest;
  ```
- You can remove any `!= 0` tests from your `if` conditions for maximum C-ness.
- You sometimes use `printf()` when you don't have to.

  > ```
  > printf("\nInvalid JSON data.\n");
  > ```

  Use `puts()` for statements like this when you aren't formatting the string.  As a plus, you don't have to include the `\n` characters.

  ```
  puts("Invalid JSON data.");
  ```